# google_maps_flutter - Map is using all available memory

Tags: ios, flutter, memory-management, google-maps-flutter

I'm currently porting a native iOS to Flutter.
I noticed that my widget containing the map is consuming a lot of memory over 500 MB.
Compared to my native iOS app, it's using x5 more memory.

I don't know what's going on cause for now I just displayed the map.
With time the app is using all the available memory and as result the application is becoming unresponsive / laggy.

Also when dispose is called on the widget, the memory used is not released, do I need to do something more in the method ?

`google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.1`
`geolocator: ^9.0.2`

Below is all I use for the map so nothing special, when I remove the map's widget, the app is running fine.
Any help is welcome, I have no idea where to look.
Thanks

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

const double CAMERA_ZOOM = 16;
const double CAMERA_TILT = 80;
const double CAMERA_BEARING = 30;

class CarteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
final _CarteWidgetState carteState = _CarteWidgetState();

Key identifier;
CarteWidget(this.identifier);

@override
_CarteWidgetState createState() => carteState;

}

class _CarteWidgetState extends State<CarteWidget> {
Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapControllerCompleter = Completer();

Map<MarkerId, Marker> _markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
Map<PolylineId, Polyline> _polylines = <PolylineId, Polyline>{};
Map<PolygonId, Polygon> _polygons = <PolygonId, Polygon>{};

List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

MapType _mapType = MapType.hybrid;
static CameraPosition _kLogeLionne = CameraPosition(
target: LatLng(48.347628, 4.383250),
zoom: 12,
);

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
}

void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
_mapControllerCompleter.complete(controller);

setState(() {
// this._loadContent();
});
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
drawer: MenuWidget(),
body: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(
      key: widget.identifier,
      initialCameraPosition: _kLogeLionne,
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_polylines.values),
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers.values),
      polygons: Set<Polygon>.of(_polygons.values),
      compassEnabled: true,
      mapType: _mapType,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
      tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
    ),
  ],
),

);
}
void _changeMapType() {
if (this.mounted) {
setState(() {
  _mapType =
      _mapType == MapType.normal ? MapType.satellite : MapType.normal;
});
}
}

}
```

`flutter doctor -v`

[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.5.0-12.0.pre.175, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 3.5.0-12.0.pre.175 on channel master at /Users/idm/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 92f10ed712 (2 days ago), 2022-11-08 17:57:52 -0800
    • Engine revision e7d7edab98
    • Dart version 2.19.0 (build 2.19.0-374.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.19.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/idm/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14A400
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.52.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPad (2) (mobile) • 0d90cccda2e8ecbf09cb57bbe0219aaf441b212d • ios            • iOS 15.6 19G71
• macOS (desktop)   • macos                                    • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)      • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.87

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!